# Save all Firefox tabs to disk as jpeg, html, pdf, png, etc

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Looking for a way to save a group of tabs in Firefox as files to disk. The files should be saved as whatever the type of page is that is being displayed, ie, html or pdf or png. (I assume based on the Content-Type). Ideally it would work on any type, ie not just images.

Basically, I want a way to hit `Ctrl+S` for a group of tabs instead of just one. And probably skip the Save As dialog.

The "Save As PDF" functionality in Foxy Tab *almost* does this for selected pdf tabs. However, it doesn't actually download the original pdfs but instead [generates new and larger pdfs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1640044).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the addon, [Save Selected Tabs to Files](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-selected-tabs-to-files/), allows you to save all of the currently-selected tabs to disk as files. A couple notes:

- The download page says to alter your `about:config` but as far as I can tell that's no longer necessary.
- You will probably want to check out the settings for the addon in the addons menu, specifically the box "Guess filename extension based on Content-Type of tabs".
- There also appears to be a bug where you can't leave the "Saved tabs under" setting blank. I haven't figured out how to set it to my root download folder...

I've been looking for an addon to allow me to save a group of image or pdf tabs, and this is the only thing I've found so far.